# How to view the page after using the crud generator of yii2

Tags: php, yii2, gii

I have used the crud generator of `yii` successfully for a model named Accounts.

It created the files and everything seems right, but when I navigate to page url it says :

> Not Found (#404)
>
> Unable to resolve the request "account".

here is the structure:

backend

```
 models
   Accounts

 controllers
   accountController

 Views
   account
     index
     _form
     _search
     create
     update
     view
```

the url `/floshal2/backend/web/index.php?r=account`

Comment: Yii is using camel-case naming mostly. accountController should be "AccountController".  However, it should have been generated that way. Try to change it an report here, if that was the cause, I'll add an answer to acceppt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yii is using camel-case naming mostly. accountController should be "AccountController".

However, it should have been generated that way. I'll open a issue on the tracker...